# Alternative way to create a java enum?

Tags: java

I have the following code that I am trying to understand:

```
public class A {    
    enum Size {S, M, L };  
    Size size = Size.M; 
}
```

I understand the first enum line is creating an enum with three values but what is the second line doing? What will the variable size hold and is this another way to construct an enum?

Comment: you have an enum called Size and three instances of that enum called S, M and L. After the second line, 'size' will contain the instance of the Size enum named M.

Answer (score 6):

The second line is just giving to the field `size` (of type `Size`) of the instance of class A the initial value `Size.M`.

You may be a little disturbed here by the fact that the enum is created inside the class `A`, it could have been in another file (but it's perfectly OK to put it inside the class A if it's used only there).

---

EDIT (not really part of the answer) : here's a (not pretty) exemple of enum declaration so that you can better understand the form of an enum declaration :

```
public enum QueryError {

    no_request("no_request", "No request in client call"),
    no_alias_requested("no_alias_requested", "no alias requested"),
    session_not_found("session_not_found", "wrong session id"),
    synosteelQuery_not_found("sxxx_not_found", "sxxx not found");

    public JsonpServerResponse.Error error;

    private QueryError(String type, String details) {
        this.error = new JsonpServerResponse.Error();
        this.error.type = type;
        this.error.detail = details;
    }
}
```

Comment: But size is an enum not a field.

Comment: No, size is the name of a reference of type Size, which happens to be the enum defined above it.

Comment: @Gemma: `size` (lowercase) is a field, of an enum type.

Comment: My confusion is that I thought the only way to construct an enum was by adding the values in curly brackets after the enum name. Is this another way?

Comment: No, there isn't. But you can put more inside those brackets that just the values (and you can do it on many lines, an enum declaration is very similar to a class declaration).

Comment: I added an example of enum declaration to make it clearer that the enum is really similar to a class, with field and method declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The second like is declaring a package private member variable of type `Size` in your class `A` and initializing it to point to `Size.M`.

Answer (score 0):

An enum is a type (just as a class is a type).  The second line is creating an instance variable called size, which has a type of Size (since an enum is a type).  Then it's initializing the value of that instance variable to an instance of the enum Size (specifically, the Size.M instance).

Comment: So I don't need to user curly braces to initialize the enum?

Comment: Curly braces are used in the *definition* of the enum; i.e. what are the possible values it can hold, as well as methods that can be executed on those value instances.  Line 2 is not a definition of an enum; it's an assignment of a particular instance (defined in Line 1) to a variable.